# React: duplicated item in list

Tags: reactjs

I'm an absolute beginner in React. I created a simple app to show an integer list on a page. There is an 'add item' button and the app happens a new integer to the list when user presses the button. When I press the button, the new integer is added twice to the list. Can anyone help?

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      idx: 0
    }

    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <div><h1>Learning app</h1>
    <ul>
      {this.state.items.map(item => (
        <li key={item}>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add Item</button>
    </div>;
  }

  addItem() {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      state.items.push(state.idx)

      return {
        items: state.items,
        idx: state.idx + 1
      }
    })
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I put this inside addItem

```
    this.state.items.push(this.state.idx);
    this.setState({
      idx: this.state.idx + 1
    })
```

it works without any issue.

I deliberately use setState with arrow function for experiment purpose. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, it will add a single item in the list

```
addItem = () => {
    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.idx],
      idx: this.state.idx + 1,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in using callback approach with `setState`.

The issue is you are mutating the the previous state array by doing `.push`. Let's keep in mind that with strict mode, [react executes `setState` twice](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856). So you are kind of mutating the prev state array twice.

**So use spread operator**

```js
addItem() {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      return {
        items: [...state.items, state.idx],
        idx: state.idx + 1
      };
    });
  }
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-item-issue-fix-yhkf1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      idx: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Learning app</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add Item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addItem = () => {
    this.setState({
      idx: this.state.idx + 1,
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.idx]
    });
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: 2+ years later, this snippet helped me sort out a funky Gatsby render issue, thanks friend. Really helped the bind I was in.